# How to print outputs on different lines and display a count in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

My task is to write an MASM application In Visual Studio 2019 (Windows) that does the following: Fill a 32-bit array with 50 random integers ... Loop through the array and display each value, and count the number of negative values. After the final loop finishes, display the count.

This is what I have for my code so far:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
array1 SWORD 50 DUP(0)
count SWORD 0

.code
main PROC
mov ecx,50
mov esi, OFFSET array1
mov esi,eax
mov ebx,0

eloop:

add esi,2
call Random32
call WriteInt
mov esi,eax
loop eloop


exit

main ENDP
END main
```

So far it seems to print 50 integers, negative and positive. My issues that I still have though, are that I'm not sure how to make each number print on different lines, and I'm not sure how to display the count of negative numbers at the end. Please assist. Thank you!

Comment: You are setting esi twice in the beginning. Do you have other subroutines available than WriteInt? Something like WriteLnInt or WriteChar? For counting you need conditional jumps (jump on less/greater/negative ...) and increment a register or memory location in one of the branches of the jump.

Comment: @Sebastian: yes, Irvine32 has a function called `Crlf` which does what you'd expect from the name.  http://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/source/irvinelib/crlf.htm also  http://math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/cs221/handouts/procedures.pdf has a list of functions.

Comment: @Sebastian Sorry - I'm pretty new at Assembly.... I'm not sure what those lines of code would look like?

Comment: @PeterCordes If I were to do a "call Crlf".. where would I call that? Just right before I exit? And is there more involved with that function?

Comment: It's just a function that prints a newline.  Call it when you want to move the cursor to the start of the next line, e.g. after every `call WriteInt`.  Obviously not just before you exit; output has already been printed by the time execution reaches that point.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, thank you very much! They all print on new lines for me now. For displaying a count of negative numbers, at the beginning do I declare some dword, then include a `jmp` for when my value is less than 0 in my eloop .. then increment the dword, then use WriteDec? This is the best I got but not sure how to implement / what it would look like, I'm a beginner in the language

Comment: Pretty sure Irvine32 has a function to print signed integers with a minus sign.  Use that.  Otherwise sure, print a `'-'` character then print the absolute value (`neg eax`) as unsigned.  Think through the logic that needs to happen separately / before the details of how to implement it.  Same for any programming language.  (Although to be fair, you do have to know what steps are even possible as a single step; e.g. string concatenation is some thing you can just do with `+` in some high level languages but not asm.)

Answer (score -1):

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myArray DWORD ?
.code
main PROC
    call Randomize
    mov myArray,EAX
    mov ECX, 50
    jmp L1
L1: 
    call Random32
    
    call WriteInt
    loop L1
    
    
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.